# Which process running on an IIS server spawns a w3wp.exe for each asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Which process running on an IIS web server is responsible for the creation of w3wp.exe worker processes for each asp.net application?

[image]

Comment: The application domain vs. application pool thing can be confusing.  I would suggest creating a new original question to address this in detail.  As far as w3wp.exe vs. aspnet_wp.exe, the different executable is because Windows 2000 and Windows XP run IIS 5.x while Windows 2003 runs IIS 6.  There are major differences in process isolation between IIS 5 and IIS 6... again, probably better to address this in a separate Q&A thread (if one doesn't already exist).

Comment: @saul: i have create a new question for appdom v.s. apppool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With IIS 7, the actual process that creates the w3wp.exe (worker process) is known as the [IIS Windows Process Activation Service (WAS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735229%28WS.10%29.aspx):

> Windows Process Activation Service
>   (WAS) manages application pool
>   configuration and the creation and
>   lifetime of worker processes for HTTP
>   and other protocols. The World Wide
>   Web Publishing Service (W3SVC) and
>   other services depend on WAS.

If you use a tool such as Process Explorer you can see the process tree including the parent process of your w3wp3.exe:

[image]

Comment: A restart of WAS cures an updated %PATH% not being seen by w3wp.exe.

Answer (score 2):

A w3wp.exe process is started for each app-pool that you have running.

There is also a process started for each element of a web-garden that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd throw in a little extra I've just found - we have a test IIS server that is inactive 90% of the time and although it has 6 application pools that are started according to the IIS management console, there were no instances of w3wp.exe running. Once I actually opened the website in my browser it spawned an instance to serve the request.